# Download File to Scope storage Android api 11

Tags: android, react-native, filesystems

I am trying to download a file and store it in scope storage for later use in react native. I'm currently using this library `react-native-scoped-storage` [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scoped-storage?activeTab=readme). How ever it only allows me to create new file and manually add data to it.

```
let addFile = await ScopedStorage.createFile(uri: string, fileName: string, mime: string);
```

I tried passing the download url as a parameter when creating a new document but it's not working.